# How to add on value to an existing value that is in a dictionary in python?

Tags: python

I am once again seeking for your help in python where I am trying to add a value to an existing dictionary. Below I have my dictionary of items and a blank dictionary.

```
Dairy_goods = {1:{'item':'Milk','p':2.47,'g':0.16,'offer':'Yes','total':0},
        2:{'item':'Butter','p':4.50,'g':0.32,'offer':'No','total':0},
        3:{'item':'Egg','p':3.40,'g':0.24,'offer':'No','total':0}}

shopping_basket={}
```

I then set a if condition where if 'Milk' is selected it will be added into the `shopping_basket{}` dictionary

```
choose=int(input('1.Item= Milk, Price= $2.47, GST= $0.16, Offer=Yes\n'
                 '2.item= Butter, Price= $4.50, GST= $0.32, Offer=No\n'
                 '3.Item= Egg, Price= $4.50, GST= $0.32, Ofer=No\n'
                 'Enter your option: '))
qnty=int(input('How many do you want?: '))
price=(Dairy_goods[choose]['p'])
y = ((Dairy_goods[choose]['p']) * qnty)
gst = (Dairy_goods[choose]['g'])
offer = (Dairy_goods[choose]['offer'])

if choose==1:
    shopping_basket['Milk'] ={'Quantity': 0 + qnty, 'Individual price': price, 'total': y, 'GST': gst, 'offer': offer}
    # cart[Menu[choose]['item']] = cart.get(Menu[choose]['item'], 0) + qnty
```

But lets say I have already selected Milk once with a Quantity of 2, and if I would want to select it again to add on to the existing Quantity, it will not add on and would simply reset and give me the Value of the new keyed in quantity.

```
#example of output
How many Milk do you want?: 2
{'Milk': {'Quantity': 2, 'Individual price': 2.47, 'total': 2.47, 'GST': 0.16, 'offer': 'Yes'}}

#selecting Milk again

How many Milk do you want? : 3 
{'Milk': {'Quantity': 3, 'Individual price': 2.47, 'total': 2.47, 'GST': 0.16, 'offer': 'Yes'}} 
# at this point I should have a quantity for 5 but it does not add on to the existing value.
```

Comment: how do you reselect milk again ? can't see any loops ? or just re running the program :\

Comment: @AliAref At this point i believe I am running this code again, Do i need a loop as you mention for the quantity to be stored?

Comment: yes! you need to store the quantity some where so that later you can add on it. now every time you running the program, `shopping_basket` initialize again and that would be **empty**. you could do either with  loop( again here it only stores **quantity** while you are looping. and on rerunning the program everything will **restart**) or store it on a file( It's a better practice you would have the stored valued on rerunning the program too, as you read it from the file)..

Comment: Ah I see, if it's not to much to ask may I ask for an example of how i would go about doing so?

Answer (score 1):

anyway you could do something like this using loops

```
Dairy_goods = {
    1: {"item": "Milk", "p": 2.47, "g": 0.16, "offer": "Yes", "total": 0},
    2: {"item": "Butter", "p": 4.50, "g": 0.32, "offer": "No", "total": 0},
    3: {"item": "Egg", "p": 3.40, "g": 0.24, "offer": "No", "total": 0},
}
shopping_basket = {}

while True:
    choose = int(
        input(
            "\n\n1.Item= Milk, Price= $2.47, GST= $0.16, Offer=Yes\n"
            "2.item= Butter, Price= $4.50, GST= $0.32, Offer=No\n"
            "3.Item= Egg, Price= $4.50, GST= $0.32, Ofer=No\n"
            "0.Exitthe program \n"
            "Enter your option: "
        )
    )

    if choose == 0:
        print("thanks!")
        break

    qnty = int(input("How many do you want?: "))
    price = Dairy_goods[choose]["p"]
    y = Dairy_goods[choose]["p"] * qnty
    gst = Dairy_goods[choose]["g"]
    offer = Dairy_goods[choose]["offer"]

    if choose == 1:
        if shopping_basket.get("Milk"):
            old_quan = shopping_basket["Milk"]["Quantity"]
        else:
            old_quan = 0
        shopping_basket["Milk"] = {
            "Quantity": old_quan + qnty,
            "Individual price": price,
            "total": y,
            "GST": gst,
            "offer": offer,
        }

    print(shopping_basket)
```

**values will be reset on rerunning the program**, to avoid this store it on file for that have look at [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-writing-text-files-python/) it may helps you more.